# Re-enumeration and Hotplug of PCIe on Linux

Tags: linux, enumeration, pci, pci-e, hotplugging

I am using PCIe device connected to linux RH6.4 machine through cable, and I need to force linux to re-enumerate the PCIe device (after its power on) without rebooting the machine.

Currently enumeration is done only after reboot. 
I tried the following but its not working

> echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/rescan

Any ideas
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doing the write you described will work only if you perform it from the Root Complex (RC) side.

Generaly speaking, a Pcie device cannot force re-enumeration.

Comment: I am assuming the OP is logged into a RH6.4 machine and that the Root Complex is located on that machine. What am I missing?